# Is it possible to change browser address bar behavior with an addon?

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible to change address bar behavior with an addon for Chrome and Firefox browsers?

To be more specific, we would like to make an add-on that will search also through our website (where we store the bookmarks of the user).
Right now we achieved it by creating an add-on and a search field comes out when the user presses on it.
However, ideally we would like that results will come directly in the address bar instead, since it's the most natural way for the user.

If that's possible, can you provide me with an add-on that does that in some way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to write a browser addon to do this.

Both Firefox and Chrome can pick up OpenSearch specifications from web pages, allowing the user to add your site as a custom search engine. For details on how to do this, see the [OpenSearch home page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch). It'll work in both browsers with no added work, it doesn't require the user to go off and install anything, and I believe it'll work in Internet Explorer as well. All around I think it's going to be a better solution for you. :)

For an example of this, Stack Overflow has an OpenSearch spec at https://stackoverflow.com/opensearch.xml. If you are using Chrome and type "stackoverflow.com" into the address bar and follow it by a space, you can do a search on the site just like you're describing.

Comment: Well, that's not what we need. 
Our search would have to autocomplete bookmarks stored from that user on OUR site, autocomplete tags, hotkeys, search directly inside bookmarks and etc.
Besides OpenSearch works on the currently open site only.

Comment: At least in Chrome, OpenSearch works for any site you have visited. You are right that you can't control completion for it, though.

Comment: Ah ok, I see now. We will implement this option also. But anyway, still not good enough. Also I don't want users to type first xxx.com and then what they are looking for.
So back to my question.. is it possible? :)